# Audio not playing using HTML5 audio tag in Phonegap app

Tags: html, cordova, audio

I've an audio file on my phone's SD card and I want to play it using my PhoneGap and HTML5 based hybrid mobile app. I am using the HTML5 audio tag as following:

`<audio src="cdvfile://localhost/myfolder/subfolder/audio.mp3"><audio>`

However unfortunately it doesn't play.

I want this to work on iOS, android and windows.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the sound file in the *www* folder, or one of its subfolders.

Comment: No, I have the audio already in my SD Card and I have to read it from there only. and not from the www folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used audio tags in Cordova applications.

I have found two cases where audio will not play:

1) use of the new WKUIWebview plugin (does not allow the file protocol in thw www folder)

2) the head is missing a content security policy, which can happen creating an app with Phonegap instead of Cordova